# Do homeomorphisms take isolated points to isolated points?

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces

I saw an statement I think it used this proposition but I'm thinking how to prove it. An attempt:

> Let $f:M\to N$ be a homeomorphism and $p$ an isolated point on $M$. So there's a $r>0$ such that $B(p,r) = \{p\}$ so $\{p\}$ is open therefore $f(\{p\})$ is open and thus is an open ball, showing that $f(p)$ is isolated.

I want to know if this is correct and, if so, how to make it more rigorous. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Assuming that $M$ and $N$ are metric spaces, your argument is correct.  More generally, $\{p\}$ is open, and $f$ is a homeomorphism, so it takes open sets to open sets.  Thus $f(\{p\})$ is open.

Comment: $f(\{p\})$ is open and thus is an open ball is a valid statement. But how do you conclude that $f(p)$ is isolated. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: @EpsilonDelta $f(\{p\}) = \{f(p)\}$ so the singleton of $f(p)$ is an open ball, then $f(p)$ is isolated.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A \subset X$, $X \cong Y$ and $f\colon\, X \rightarrow Y$ a homeomorphism.

Assume that $x \in Iso(A) \subset X\,$ so $\,x \in U \in \mathcal T_X\,$ s.t. $\,(\,U \setminus \{x\})\, \cap A = \emptyset$
$\stackrel{*}{\Rightarrow} f(U) \in \mathcal T_Y\,$ s.t. $\,(\,f(U) \setminus f(x))\, \cap f(A) = \emptyset$

$\Rightarrow f(x) \in Iso(f(A)) \subset Y.$

$*$) $f$ is a homeomorphism i.e. bijection and open.

Thus homeomorphisms preserve isolated points.

Above $\mathcal T_X$ and $\mathcal T_Y$ mean topologies for $X$ and $Y$.